# How to change the callback function in mootools class Request.JSONP

Tags: mootools, jsonp

I'm using the Request.JSONP to get some data, but I need to change the callback function in the url that retrieve de data.

Using the example in the documentation:

How to change this call:

http://www.flickr.com/?format=json&jsoncallback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0

to this:

http://www.flickr.com/?format=json&jsoncallback=myOwnFunction

In jQuery you can use the setting "jsonpCallback" to use your own function, but I can't find a way to change it in MooTools.

Any help, ideas, will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

My problem is that my function is going to be in a setInterval function and every time it executes the requested url change like this:

callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0

callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_1

callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_2...n

I need that the last digit doesn't change (for cache purposes)

Answer (score 1):

it's called `callbackKey` for JSONP. [read the doc](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP).

here's a flickr class that extends jsonp that i wrote (change api pls):

```
// the class
Request.flickr = new Class({
    Extends: Request.JSONP,
    options: {
        callbackKey: "jsoncallback",
        url: "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?",
        log: true
    },
    initialize: function(params, options) {
        this.parent(options);
        this.options.url = this.options.url + Object.toQueryString(params);
    },
    success: function(data, script) {
        this.parent(data, script);
    },
    imageURL: function(obj) {
        return "http://farm{farm}.static.flickr.com/{server}/{id}_{secret}.jpg".substitute(obj);
    }
});

// example on how to use
new Request.flickr({
    format: 'json',
    api_key: "e7df6c74d2545f55414423463bf99723", // your api here
    per_page: 4,
    tags: "mountains",
    method: "flickr.photos.search"
}, {
    onSuccess: function(data) {
        target = document.id("action");
        var self = this;
        data.photos.photo.each(function(el) {
            new Asset.image(self.imageURL(el), {
                onload: function() {
                    this.inject(target);
                }
           });
        });
    }
}).send();
```

To completely override the callback and pass on an external function (needs to be global):

```
window.foo = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};


Request.flickr = new Class({
    Extends: Request.JSONP,
    options: {       
        url: "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=foo&",
        log: true
    },
    initialize: function(params, options) {
        this.parent(options);
        this.options.url = this.options.url + Object.toQueryString(params);
    },
    success: function(data, script) {
        this.parent(data, script);
    },
    imageURL: function(obj) {
        return "http://farm{farm}.static.flickr.com/{server}/{id}_{secret}.jpg".substitute(obj);
    }
});

// example on how to use
new Request.flickr({
    format: 'json',
    api_key: "e7df6c74d2545f55414423463bf99723",
    // your api here
    per_page: 4,
    tags: "mountains",
    method: "flickr.photos.search"
}).send();
```

the above code will run the function foo, passing on the JSON object to it. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/DUtff/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm checking your code and I see that the requested url is: 

http://www.flickr.../?jsoncallback=foo&format=json&api_key=*&method=flickr.photos.search&callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0

Is there any way to remove or change the last part? (callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0)

My problem is that my function is going to be in a setInterval function and every time it executes the requested url change like this:

callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0
callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_1...n

I need not change the last digit

Comment: then don't use Request.JSONP but write your own wrapper via Asset.javascript or something. Request.JSONP will always output it. you can refactor it and get it to not do it, though.

Comment: Ok, thaks for the suggestions